# Ошибка: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not ''

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Я только начал писать на Swift и мне довольно сложно разобраться в проблеме(

```
 func prepareCamera() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

    if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices {
        captureDevice = availableDevices.first
        beginSession()
    }

}

func beginSession () {
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

    }catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    if let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) {


        captureSession.startRunning()

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]

        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()






    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KZj7.png

Answer (score 0):

В обоих случаях у вас в правой части выражения if let стоит объект, не являющийся Optional. Конструкция if let предназначена только для Optional-типов, из-за чего код и не компилируется. Используйте вместо конструкции if let просто let, и все должно заработать.

Comment: Я уже пробовал( после этого появляются другие 3 ошибки: 1. Cannot call value of non-function type '[AVCaptureDevice]'  2. Variable used within its own initial value | 3. Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer' with an argument list of type '(session: AVCaptureSession, () -> ())'